# applying background to first, and every third row in a dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a table that its' rows are dynamically generated. I am hiding the second row so the user can expand that row if he or she chooses to do so. I need to have an alternating background for every first and third row, and the second row will take the background color of the row before it.. Here's a picture to help explain:

[image]

The CSS I am currently using is this: (Provided from @rusmus)

```
.tbody tr:nth-child(4n), tbody tr:nth-child(4n- 1){
      background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

And here is a link to his working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lutkz/1/

For some reason though, it's not applying the color to the  after the affected  like the jsfiddle

Side note: The whole table is in a foreach() that displays each row from the database into the table.

Code of the table:

```
    <div class="table-wrapper" id="monthly-payers">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="portfolio table table-striped-improved">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="persist essential security">Security</th>
        <th class="persist essential">Symbol</th>
        <th class="optional">Number<br>of Shares</th>
        <th class="optional">Cost<br>Basis</th>
        <th>Current<br>Price</th>
        <th>Stock<br />Return %</th>
        <th>Buy<br>Under</th>
        <th>Dividend<br>Yield</th>
        <th>Ex-Dividend<br>Date</th>
        <th class="persist">Payout<br>Date</th>
        <th>Cumulative<br>Dividend</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php if( isset($open_trades['monthly-payers']) && !empty($open_trades['monthly-payers']) ){ ?>
<?php foreach( $open_trades['monthly-payers'] as $trade ){ 
      $numShares = empty($trade['num_shares'])? 1 : intval($trade['num_shares']);

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $trade['security']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $trade['symbol']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo !empty($trade['num_shares']) ? $trade['num_shares'] : '&ndash;'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo is_numeric($trade['entry_price']) ? '$' . sprintf("%.02f", $trade['entry_price']) : '&ndash;'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo is_numeric($trade['current_price']) ? '$' . sprintf("%.02f", $trade['current_price']) : '&ndash;'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo (is_numeric($trade['current_price']) && is_numeric($trade['entry_price'])) ? sprintf("%.02f", ($trade['current_price'] - $trade['entry_price']) / $trade['entry_price'] * 100)."%" : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo is_numeric($trade['buy_under']) ? '$' . sprintf("%.02f", $trade['buy_under']) : '&ndash;'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo is_numeric($trade['dividend_yield']) ? sprintf("%.02f", $trade['dividend_yield']) . '%' : '&ndash;'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date('m/d/y', $trade['ex_dividend_date']); ?><?php echo !empty($trade['estimated']) ? ' Est.' : ''; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date('m/d/y', $trade['payout_date']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo is_numeric($trade['total_dividend']) ? '$' . $trade['total_dividend'] : '&ndash;'; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $trade['stock_type']; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

That second row, $trade['stock_type'] is what is causing the whole thing to go wonky.

I am going to have comments in that row that the user can hide, or show, that's why I need the alternating color to skip that row, and just apply the color of the  above it.. (which changes with each row in the foreach())

Comment: Do you mean that there is a comment row for each ordinary row in the table... Are you actually trying to make the rows the same color in pairs?

Comment: Per say. I want the first row, and second row to look as a pair with the same background (green), and then the 3rd and fourth row will look like a pair with the same background (white) and so on@rusmus

Comment: I made a new fiddle that I think solves your problem. I've updated my answer with a new link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you're wanting is for the rows to alternate 2 at a time. So they go `dark dark, light light, dark dark`

I think, similar to @rusmus solution, you should apply a class to the rows.

Put this right before your `foreach` loop:

```
$black = true;
$rownumber = 0;
```

Put this in your loop

```
if(($rownumber % 2) == 0){//if the number is even
    $black = !$black;  //switch the state

    if($black){
        $class = 'blackRow';
    }else{
        $class = 'whiteRow';
    }
}  
$rownumber++;
```

Basically what I've done is check if the row number is even. If it is, then we switch the color from being light to dark.

On your table row do something like this:
    `<tr class='<?php echo $class; ?>' >`

Here's a codepad example:
http://codepad.org/JR4KOri4

Comment: I changed if(($rownumber % 2) == 0){//if the number is even to > if(($rownumber % 1) == 0){//if the number is even and it works great! Can you update your answer so the 2 = 1 so other people viewing this have the correct answer? Thanks man!

Comment: Hmmm....I don't see how changing the modulus can possibly make it work. Are you sure you don't have someone else's code still active. For example, @rusmus solution is pretty good, and if you have both solutions implemented, his might take precedence. If you change the divisor to 1, there's no way this code will work.     Here is the link to the modulus documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: I added a codepad example. You can change the settings to confirm one method over the other.

Comment: I deleted out all of @rusmus's code, and when I have a 1 in place of the 2, it works flawlessly. No other modifide code, nothing.. Not quite sure what the deal is, but I excepted your answer.

Comment: I would think that this indicates that you have some rows that are hidden by css, or you html is somehow mangled. The answer @TimSum gave is definitely correct, and my own answer works on IE9+, Firefox and Chrome so there must be something going on with your markup that we are not seeing...

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using two rows for 1 row of information?
You could put a linebreak `<br/>` after "Advent Claymore Convertible Securities & Income Fund", then the `t` is showed on the next line and you get the colors you want. Like this:

`<td><?php echo $trade['security']; ?><br/><?php echo $trade['security']; ?></td>`
instead of

`<td><?php echo $trade['security']; ?></td>`

Comment: If i have this second row inside the security name column, the comments will not take up 100% width of the table. IT would be squished into the corner with the security name. I want the comments to take up 100% of the table UNDERNEATH the rest of the content for that security. @roySchoep

Comment: You could use a `<div>` tag for example instead of the table row and style it accordingly, then you don't need advanced css selectors.

Comment: When I use a div tag though in that table, it breaks out of the table and appears above it..

Answer (score 2):

You could just apply a class to the rows that you want to have a different background, and target that class in css.

But if you want to do it without modifying you markup you could do something like:

```
tr:nth-child(4n), tr:nth-child(4n - 1){
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

The above selects every 4th row, as well as the row before it. An illustration:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr> <!-- row 4n - 1 (for n=1) -->
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr> <!-- row 4n (for n=1) -->
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr> <!-- row 4n - 1 (for n=2) -->
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr> <!-- row 4n (for n=2) -->
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lutkz/1/

Checked to work in chrome, firefox, ie11, ie10 and ie9.

Comment: Good solution, but looks like it's not supported in chrome 32

Comment: I loaded that example up in Chrome & Firefox and it did not appear to  work in either of them. Thanks for your help on this though man!

Comment: You're the man! Let me plug this into my code and test it. @rusmus

Comment: Could you edit your answer to give a brief explanation on what the CSS is doing and how it works for me/future people looking at this? @rusmus

Comment: Alright so I plugged it in, and this is what it looks like:
http://imgur.com/C1DB0at it's not applying that change to the row underneath the red for some reason

Comment: I've updated my answer with a description of what the css does. Can you provide a link to the site, so I can see what the generated markup looks like? If not, could you update the question with an example?

Comment: I updated my code. The site requires a login and a couple other things so it's not really possible to have you see it :/

Comment: Hey thanks man for all your help! I went with @timsum answer because it accommodated IE8.. Thanks for all your help though!