# How to hide randomly generated row of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, lightbox

HI coder i have a gridview in which data comes from database.. now id of all row is same what i want it to show only first row of my gridview and hide rest of the others but not their value i just wana hide them. i want their value because i have a lightbox on it.

this is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="1" PersistedSelection="true" 
    DatakeyNames="pptId,Priority">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="pptId" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblpptId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pptId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>    
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPriority" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Priority") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View PPT">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("Imageurl") %>' title='<%#Eval("Description") %>'
                        rel="lightbox[Brussels]" runat="server">Start PPT</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                
        </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
         </asp:GridView>
```

EDIT::

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindModule();

}
protected void BindModule()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string id = Request.QueryString["pptId"].ToString();
        //Query to get Imagesurl and Description from database
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Image_Master where pptId='" + id + "' and IsEnable='True' order by Priority", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        da.Fill(dt);          
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();                      
        GridView1.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error occured : " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

in the above code pptId is same for each row, my images show inside my gridview what i want is to show only first images and hide rest of other but not their values..

how to i do that.....thanks in advance

Comment: So you just want to display the first row without deleting the others?

Comment: yup i dont want to delete them i just want to hide them pptId is same for each row but imageurl and priority is different... just like you can say 1 ppt have 5 images with different priority so i m showing images of 1st ppt but in gridview i wana show only first and hide rest of them so that i have their value so that my lightbox work on it

Comment: Not sure i get it... why hiding the whole row if priotity and imageurl are different? Don't you want to hide the first cell for each row?

Comment: no mate i dont wana hide pptId i just want to show first row of gridview because when i click on my first images a slideshow will start it and i only want first images of that pptId, if i use top(1) query then my lightbox will show only that image not all images in slideshow that's why mate i hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do this with css?

```
table tr:nth-child(n + 3) {
    display: none;
}
```

There is an explanation of the nth-child css-selector here:

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

I've also explained it in another answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21166162/1256868

You would probably need a class or a static id on the generated table so you can single that table out, but still...

Edit following comments:

Try adding a css class to the gridview and adding the css above like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.Grid tr:nth-child(n + 3) {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="Grid">
        <%--Your templates here--%>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Asp.net will generate an html table from your gridview, that is why you need to apply styling to a table. The browser never sees any asp.net code. That code is simply a way of generating html that the browser knows how to display.

Edit regarding better IE support:

I guess what you are asking is for IE8 (and possibly 7) support, as IE9 and up support nth-child. To support IE7 and up, change your css to use the + selector, which has better support:

```
table.Grid tr + tr + tr{    
    display: none;
}
```

The + selector is the adjacent sibling selector. The selector `tr + tr` thus selects any tr that immediatly follows another tr element. For further exaplnation see: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ (specifically the section titled 'Adjacent sibling combinator').

Comment: my friend i can do that with css but my image path comes from database to tell how can i use it.. i am just asking is it possible to do that just like www.slideshare.net site has but its now automatic slideshow

Comment: It doesn't matter where your data comes from. Using the above css, you simply hide every row in the table, except the first. The rows will still be in the generated markup, and will still be accessible through javascript, but will not be displayed on screen.

Comment: Hi rusmus they are randomly generated rows and columns

Comment: I assume you are using a js library for the lightbox. Can you tell me which one?

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/jquery-lightbox-image-slideshow-gallary.html view this link from here i use all the lightbox js

Comment: So you are trying to follow the tutorial that you linked to, but you are using a gridview instead of a datalist, and you only want to show the first image to begin with, but if someone clicks that image, it should open a lightbox where the user can see all the images? So you can show all the images already, your are just trying to hide every row except the first?

Comment: i use this tutorial but not completely i use lightbox details from this tutorial and yes you are right i only want to show the first image to begin with, but if someone clicks that image, it should open a lightbox where the user can see all the images. i just trying to hide every row except the first

Comment: But you can get your gridview to display all the images that you want to be in the lightbox?

Comment: yes but my motive is to show images of a pptId which i get from a query string which i get from another page and on show.aspx page i only want to show first images in my gridview related to that pptId but when i click on that images lightbox start slideshow.. i hope u understand what i am trying to say

Comment: And did you try adding the css I posted to your show.aspx page? What happened when you added the css? Did it get you closer to a solution or did it not work at all. If it didn't help you, please try posting some of the generetad html from your page, as that might clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: rusmus where to put your code in my code mate as i m using gridview not table so if u can give me code for table i will add it

Comment: @Amy I've made an edit to illustrate how to use the css.

Comment: hi rusmus when i apply that css my gridview will show only header text not more than that

Comment: I've updated the answer with links to explanations of the nth-child selector.

Comment: I there is one thing which comes into my project now my boss want me to run this application on ie and nth doesn't support ie can you help me now

Comment: @Amitesh I've updated my answer with an alternative that has better browser support. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rusmus let me try on my application which i host on server it your previous and present both work locally let me try it on server

Answer (score 1):

I think it's what you are looking for :

```
for(int i = 1; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
}
```

Use it after binding datasource to GridView1 in code behind.

Comment: thanks make your code is good but it also false the value of other rows of gridview which i dont want i just want to hide them but their value should be functional.. i cant upvote your ans coz my reputation is low and can't accept that answer mate

Comment: How do you access the value with your lightbox?

Comment: i edit my question c my updated question see my aspx page code