# Display lightbox gallery without displaying the whole gallery on document

Tags: lightbox, nivo-slider

Is it possible to display a Nivo Lightbox Gallarey (or any other responsive lightbox) with for example 4 pictures when a user clicks on a single picture? (the other 3 pictures are hidden and only displayed in the lightbox)

Comment: yes it is possible go to that link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379242/how-to-hide-randomly-generated-row-of-gridview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy with Nivo. Simply create empty anchors for the other images

```
<a href="images/gallery-img-001.jpg" class="gallery-start" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"><img src="images/gallery-thumb-004.jpg" width="365" height="245" /></a>
<a href="images/gallery-img-002.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
<a href="images/gallery-img-003.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
<a href="images/gallery-img-004.jpg" class="gallery-thumb-hidden" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1"></a>
```

Then call the gallery from JQuery

```
$('a.gallery-start').nivoLightbox({...
```