# How to use nth child in IE

Tags: css, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, lightbox

I have a grid-view in which i am showing my images.
Now i use css nth child to hide all my rows except first row of grid-view so that when i click on link a slideshow of images start

For slide show i am using lightbox.

Code for nth chlid is like this

```
<style type="text/css">
    table.Grid tr:nth-child(n + 3) {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

and use that css on my grid-view

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="Grid">
    <%--My templates here--%>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now that work fine in crome and mozila but not in IE how can i use it in IE or any other thing to show only first row and hide other rows and i want to hide rows dont want to make them invisible

Any help will be apprecialted....!!! for more you can see my previous question

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379242/how-to-hide-randomly-generated-row-of-gridview)

Comment: Which IE version you intend to support? I think nth only work in IE9+ with no compatibility mode enabled.

Comment: Because the application i created should work on IE as per my boss order

Comment: Check this w3school tutorial it might work http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: This wont support ie8 check this one too http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/  http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: Sorry I think I misspelled something or did not make myself clear. I understood you need to support IE. But what are the versions you need to support? If you need to support IE7 or IE8 I think you are out of luck.

Comment: I am using IE 9 and its not working on it is there any turn around for nth class to hide rows of gridview and show only first row Sry i forgot to mention one thing on localhost it work fine but on server rather then hiding all record and show first row it show all record

Answer (score 1):

`nth-child` will only work in ie9+ -- see http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Also, `nth-child(n + 3)` will select every 3rd element, not the first. For a full guide to using `nth-child` see http://nthmaster.com/.

Comment: i am using IE 9 and its not working on it is there any turn around for nth class to hide rows of gridview and show only first row

Comment: Sry i forgot to mention one thing on localhost it work fine but on server rather then hiding all record and show first row it show all record